# Sql Alchemy connection time Out

Tags: python, session, timeout, sqlalchemy

I am using `sqlalchemy` with `MySQL`, and executing query with sql expression. When executing a number of query then it time out. I found an [answer](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/b2bf9687aaee38af/cd9bcaed89b4dbb8) but it is not clear to me. Please, any one can help me?

> TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30

Comment: It depends on how are you using sessions and how do you create your engine. If you use thread-local sessions, and amount of threads is larger than your connections pool size you defined in engine(), you just need to raise size of pool. If you use single-threaded application, then Greg is correct and you are leaking non-closed sessions. You can fix this by either enforcing single-session-per-thread behavior, or ensuring you always close your sessions, for example with `with` syntax.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Whenever you create a new session in your code, make sure you close it.  Just call `session.close()`

When I got this error I thought I was closing all of my sessions, but I looked carefully and there was one new method where I wasn't.  Closing the session in that method fixed this error for me.

Comment: is it absolutely necessary to close sessions? Shouldn't be the connection back to pool when session is deleted (out of scope)?

Comment: This is something I've found perplexing. Why doesn't `close()` get called when the session goes out of scope?

Comment: Make sure you also close the sessions when exceptions fire. The sqlalchemy docs suggest using a context manager to deal with this (among other solutions).

Comment: I don't see how to 'close the sessions' as I'm calling engine.execute(statement).

Answer (score 13):

In multi-thread mode, if your concurrent request num is much more than the db connection pool size, it will throw the Queue Pool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached **`error`**. try with this:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://', convert_unicode=True, 
pool_size=20, max_overflow=100)

to add the pool size
```

Add: the method above is not a correct way. The actual reason is that db connection pool is used up, and no other available connection. The most probably situation is you miss to release connection. For example:

```
@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    db_session.remove()
```

Comment: FYI: This is for flask only.